# Trying to get a Start Date from a Team City Sharp Server

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, teamcity

This is my code to get a Json connection to a TeamCitySharp server.  The localhost is my Json connection.  Right now, I am trying to get the start date to display when I go to my localhost, but it displays as null.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:81/Status/AllStatuses");
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.RegisterConverters((new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() }));
            dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(responseString, typeof(object));

            foreach (var objects in obj)
            {       

                foreach (var project in client.Projects)
                {


                    foreach (var build in project.Builds)
                    {
                        bs.date = project.ProjectStartDate.ToString();
```

This is on another controller in a separate project to call the Jsonresult.

```
public JsonResult AllStatuses() //from the json called in the _client view
    {
        var buildStatuses = new List<BuildStatus>();

        var projects = Client.AllProjects();

        //var projects = storeDB.Projects.Include("Builds").ToList();
        //var buildStatuses = new List<BuildStatus>();


        foreach (var project in projects)
        {
            try 
            {
                var buildConfigs = Client.BuildConfigsByProjectId(project.Id);

                foreach (var buildConfig in buildConfigs)
                {
                    var build = Client.LastBuildByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id);

                    var b = new BuildStatus();
                    b.id = buildConfig.Id.ToString();
                    if (b.date != null)
                        b.date = b.date.ToString();
                    if (b.status != null)
                        b.status = build.Status.ToString();
                    buildStatuses.Add(b);
                }
            } catch { }
        }
        //var query = buildStatuses.OrderBy(x => x.status); // Create a sorted list from Error - Unknown               

        return Json(buildStatuses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: My bs (buildstatus) is a POCO.

Comment: I can replicate the issue but have no fix

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this question is still relevant for the person who asked it. I will answer it for others who might encounter the same issue.

There is a FluentTc library, which provides easy access to TeamCity via its REST API. There is a way to retrieve builds with their start and/or finish dates:

`IList builds =
    new RemoteTc().Connect(h => h.ToHost("teamcity.codebetter.com").AsGuest())
        .GetBuilds(b =>
            b.BuildConfiguration(c =>
                c.Id("FluentTc_FluentTcDevelop"))
                .Branch(r => r.Branched()),
            i => i.IncludeStatusText().IncludeStartDate().IncludeFinishDate());`

The library is available as a nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/fluenttc